# Android: how to show a dynamic table that is create in 1 class to show in another class also

Tags: android, android-activity, tablelayout

I am making an android app in which i want to make a dynamic table layout and rows into it.
Now i want to use the table layout in another activity That is I dont want to make same table in the second activity.
How shall i accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

Define your layout in one xml file. ex one.xml

use following code, in which ever xml you want.

```
<include android:id="@+id/one" layout="@layout/one"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: I just want to include the same  table layout in the second activity not the whole layout?

Comment: define table layout separately and include in both the activities...!